# map vs unordered map

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I am implementing certain algorithm and I use in this algorithm `map<string,map<string,double>>`. It works perfectly, giving correct results but if I change `map<string,map<string,double>>` for `unordered_map<string,map<string,double>>`, my algorithm stops working for certain inputs.

I want to ask if I am missing something in the difference between `unordered_map` and `map`. Is there any essential thing that may cause this?

**EDIT**: It is Floyd-Warshall algorithm and I do not think there woul be a problem with data sorting. Onlt thing I am using map for is just for making a matrix with info about edge value between 2 nodes.

Comment: what algorithms? what do you mean by "stops working"?

Comment: It could be that your program invokes undefined behavior at some point, and this happens to luckily do what you want with `map<,>` but not with `unordered_map<,>`. Please post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Floyd-Warshall .. I can not release that, that's why I am asking if there is any difference that may cause this. I think there should not be a difference. Only in the things like time complexity

Comment: *for unordered_map<string,map<string,double>>, my algorithm stops working for certain inputs.* -- Then you need to debug this implementation.  A program "working perfectly" means nothing in the world of C++, especially if you have an example of where it should work correctly and it doesn't.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it seems fair to debug this implementation but I am asking if there is any radical difference between those that can cause this. I am not aware of any.. By the way I have edited the question

Comment: There's not enough information to go on. I mean it could be running out of memory or X-rays bit flipping or thermal overload causing other bizarre anomalies . Could also be that your algorithm expects a repeatable ordering which unordered doesn't guarantee. Or...

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what algorithm that is. `map` will automatically sort it's elements by key while `unordered_map` wont bother with that.

Therefore you will probably find that even though the data contained in them is the same, it is in different order and that is interfering with your result.

`map` is best for static data, the fact the keys are ordered allows it to find things faster. Sorting it however can be time consuming, so if you need a `map` but it will be constantly modified, `unordered_map` can become the faster option.

Comment: Edited -> added algorithm

Comment: *"`map` is best for static data, the fact the keys are ordered allows it to find things faster."* I dispute this claim. Lookup in a `map` has O(log n) time complexity, while lookup in an `unordered_map` has average O(1) time complexity. Whether one will actually be faster than the other in wall time depends on the number of elements, the number of collisions in the unordered map, and the access patterns of the application.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm no expert in calculating "time complexity", but based on what I know about binary search it seems to me the number of attempts required to find an element in `unordered_map` is between 1 and the number of elements, while in `map` is between 1 and logarithm of the number of elements, and looking at it this way it's clear which one is faster. The log of a number can't possibly be larger than itself.

Comment: @Havenard *"between 1 and the number of elements"* -- Technically true. In the average case it will be 1. That is to say, if your hash function isn't complete garbage and generation a ton of collisions. You only ever have to perform more than one attempt if there was a hash collision (one bucket occupied by more than one item). In any decent unordered_map implementation with a good hash function, collisions will be rare. The "worst case" of O(n) only happens if *every element hashes to the same bucket*, which is statistically impossible with a good hash function.

Comment: @Havenard In other words, 99% of the time you will be performing one attempt and arriving at exactly the item you wanted (or not finding it in the bucket at all). Whether the overhead of computing the hash outperforms a binary search depends on the number of items in the map. There is some integer (0 <= x <= infinity) where when the number of items is less than x, `map` will be faster for lookups; when the number of items is greater than or equal to x, `unordered_map` will be faster for lookups. Basically when the hash function is just as fast as the O(log n) binary search.

Comment: @cdhowie What makes you assume that? It's an `unordered_map`, it has no index. The only way to always find the element you're looking for on the first attempt is if it only has 1 element.

Comment: @cdhowie And I can use any custom object I want as key and `unordered_map` wont know how to hash that and won't require a function from me like `map` does, so I'm not sure what all that hash talk is about.

Comment: Besides, by comparing O(log n) with O(1) you are basically saying any `map` with more than only 10 elements would be better off being an `unordered_map`, and that sounds pretty absurd.

Comment: @Havenard "unordered" does not mean "flat list," it means that the elements aren't ordered on the key. The underlying structure of `unordered_map` is a hashtable.

Comment: @Havenard The performance cutoff could very well be 10, depending on the complexity of the hash function.

Comment: @Havenard To clarify something you said: *"And I can use any custom object I want as key and `unordered_map` wont know how to hash that"* -- You are right. [It's an error, in fact](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81af511d31a86096), to use a custom object as a key without specializing `std::hash<>` for it. (Note: `error: no match for call to '(const std::hash<A>) (const A&)'`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unordered_map contains unordered data. So if you algorithm need ordered data the alogirtm will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so - answer for my question is: There is not any other fundamental difference between `map` and `unordered_map`. If I do not need sorted data and I just change `map` for `unordered_map`, everything is okay.

I think, it was not such problem to say that there is not difference between those two except of sorted data.